# How to check the header text of a DataGridView column of a selected cell in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview in visual basic. I want to adjust a sub to accomplish the following task: When a user selects a cell in my DGV (Cell Click event) I want to check the column header text. And in my example, if the header text of the column is "MinEquation" then I want to execute some event. The reason I cannot use column indices is that I create these DGV's dynamically in a loop with different datatables. How can I do a comparison operator on the column header text of my selected cell. Thank you!

Comment: Your cell click event has the index of the column you clicked.  Use that index to access the Columns array of the DGV.  It won't matter what order you created the columns in.  Just watch out for the user clicking on the row header which will be column -1.

Comment: Thank you for the help. How to I now reference that grid view? Like to access the properties of it.

Comment: The first argument of every event handler is the sender of the event.  It's always an Object, but since you know the event is coming from your DGV, you can DirectCast(sender, DataGridView).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would generate the DataGridView's [CellClick event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use the [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) to return the column's information. Take a look at this example:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText = "MinEquation" Then
        'Match
    End If
End Sub
```